# Why I am getting this error when compiling OpenVino samples

Tags: c++, openvino

I build samples using the process that explained in documentation and I can open the solution in windows 10.

When I try to compile the code (using VS 2017), I am getting this error:

```
Error   C3861   '_mm_blendv_ps': identifier not found   ie_cpu_extension    C:\local\Intel\computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445\deployment_tools\inference_engine\src\extension\common\softmax.h  81
```

Why am I getting this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: which target are you compiling for? x86, x64 or ARM?

Comment: @PeterT  the target is x64

Comment: odd, should work with the default compilation settings according to [this test](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9SA04l)

Comment: @PeterT Yes it is odd! Does the CPU model matters? I think the CPU that I have is relatively on old i5 CPU.

Comment: the compiling CPU shouldn't matter much. The target CPU is what should matter and the intrinsic mentioned is SSE4.1 which should be available on all x64 targets

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the softmax.h header includes the header smmintrin.h (since that is the one responsible for the SSE4.1 intrinsics).
Hope this solves the problem.